# I've been trying to return numbers to a multidimensional int array in Java

Tags: java, arrays, methods

I have been trying to code a game for my comp. sci. class and I've been having trouble
getting values to transfer between methods for a 2D int array.

The code I've currently have is as follows:

```
public int assignDeck(){
    int k = 1;
    int[][] deckNum = new int[4][13];
    for (int i=0;i<4;i++){
        for (int j=0;j<13;j++){
            deckNum[i][j] = k;
        }
        k++;
    }       
    return new int[][]deckNum;
}
```

As it stands, my program is telling me "incompatible types: int[] cannot be converted to int" on the return line, as well as an error from the bracket below from what I assume is the return statement not being acknowledged as proper code.

I'm not sure how to get each value to transfer to the array in my main method:

```
int [][] deckNum = assignDeck();
```

This line of code is getting "non-static method assignDeck() cannot be referenced from a static context" as an error. All I need it to do is transfer the values for my array from "assignDeck" to my main method.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Use static and declare arrays as return type.

```
public static int[][] assignDeck() {
   ...
   return deckNum;
}
```